# Update all list element based on the function result

Tags: android, kotlin

There are loads of examples on the internet and on stackoverflow. But as far as I can see it is implemented according to index. But I want all items to be updated based on a single function result.

Below example is my simpyfied version:

```
data class Person(val id: Int, val name: String)

var tempList: List<Pair<Person, Boolean?>> = emptyList()


val personList = listOf(Person(1, "1"), Person(2, "2"), Person(3, "3"))

fun processPerson(person: Person): Boolean {    
    return person.name == "1"
}

fun main() {
    tempList = personList.map { item ->
        Pair(item, null)
    }
    
    tempList.forEach { item ->
        println(processPerson(item.first))
    }
}
```

Expected updated version of my list is:

```
listOf(Pair(Person(1, "1"), true), Pair(Person(2, "2"), false), Pair(Person(3, "3"), false))
```

Answer (score 2):

You could have constructed the list right away with

```
tempList = personList.map { item ->
    Pair(item, processPerson(item))
}
```

If you really need to work with the initial `tempList` then all you can do is

```
tempList = tempList.map { 
    Pair(it.first, processPerson(it.first))
}
```

or

```
tempList = tempList.map {
    it.copy(second = processPerson(it.first))
}
```

There's no way to update the original Pairs because their values are immutable so the only option is to map to new Pairs